# Creating a launcher (for Mechinarium)

Tags: games, flash

I'm trying to make a launcher for Mechinarium, Its a flash game with a launcher that runs flash files in separate folders in its directory as far as im aware. 
I've tried to make a launcher which points towards this executable which runs fine when i click on it. When i try and run it from the launcher the player comes up (black screen) and i can right click and get the flash options however the game does not load.

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

EDIT - ANSWER:
http://machinarium.net/forum/index.php/topic,467.0.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a few issues like this with various things. I find the best way to fix these is to write a little shell script and stick it in `~/bin`.

Here's what I did for Nexuiz (which had some path issues):

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Nexuiz
./nexuiz-linux-x86_64-sdl
```

You obviously don't want that path or that executable but basically `cd` to the right place and *then* run it.

Don't forget to `chmod +x` the script. And then just have your launcher call the script.

Your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/will/Machinarium
./Machinarium
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused.
The executable is located under /home/will/Machinarium
so would my script look like this?
http://pastebin.com/mKKv7nm7
That doesn't run even after running chmod +x on it
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: @rocker9455 See my edited post.

Comment: Ah, Well the link to the forum post ended up not working, yours did work however! Thanks a lot, this is great

Answer (score 0):

You can create a launch script and put it into `/usr/local/bin`.

Furthermore, you can create a menu entry that points to the script to be able to launch it from your menus. In KDE you can use kmenuedit for this, Gnome has a similar menu editor too.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already made a launcher, it just doesnt open the game up properly, it doesnt read the .swf files